# how to use html and javascript in developing native android app

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am developing an android sales app which is working integrated ERP (1C,SAP doesn't matter which). I have experience developing android apps but my boss restricted me from using Android GUI tools. The requirement is to develop the client side (GUI) with JavaScript and HTML.

I always developed use Android GUI tools. How can I create a native Android app with HTML/JavaScript GUI?  (I'm using Java for the backend.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ionic to do that. Using HTML, and AngularJS and javascript to develop your android app. Not only android but also Windows and IOS apps. Check this out:

[Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/)

If you are a Windows user, download Visual Studio 2015, then install the ionic template on visual studio following the link below:

http://dustinewers.com/how-to-ionic-in-visual-studio/

Comment: thank you, I'll research that.

Comment: Yes I have just recently developed an Android app using Ionic in Visual Studio 2015, and the app works in my android phone. The app is using HTML, CSS, javascript and as for backend, it uses AngularJS. Very good thing is it is free. If you use Xamarin, most probably you will need to pay because the free version has limitations.

Comment: I have to use java on backend side. I'll use javascript and html for just gui design. Is that possible in your offer?

Comment: It is possible, however I haven't the experience in that. This link might help you:
http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/java-as-backend-need-explanation/30799

Comment: Thank you, I need to documents, examples etc about that, you may not have an experience about this but ıf you can show some way (like this link) it's very important for me. Thank you again, I'll look this link when I'll arrive home. If you know another examples about this subject Could you share with me?

Comment: Although this question is not closed, in 2017 there is no better solution but React Native to create native apps using Javascript. I have put together a small tutorial at http://geekycentral.com/creating-a-native-android-app-using-javascript-hello-react-native/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Cordova that is a crossplatform framework by Apache.

https://cordova.apache.org/

With this framework you can create view based on HTML/CSS code and logic coded in JS. You can also create a custom native plugin to have access to Android platform features. http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins

This framework is crossplatform, it works on iOS,WP,BB etc, but ofcourse, custom native plugins must be writed for all platforms if u need it.

PS for Cordova you can find a lot of plugin already developed online

Comment: Thank you I'll look this